# Vue js data logic - booking table

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to make a table of bookings (the `hours` are the `y`, the `slots` (actually tennis courts) the `x`).

- I will populate an array from my database with the already occupied
  slots **(court 5 at 5PM,...)**;
- I'll then loop trough all possibilities (from 7AM to 12PM and for
  each hour, every slots) and put the booking's name when taken, and
  put a button when it's not.

I can't figure out how to structurate my data;

In **Php** I had an array like `$bookings[$hour][$court]` which, when **not empty**, should contain the booking name (in the php nested loops (hours and courts), I checked if `$bookings[$hour][$court]` was empty (and then display the content if any or a button otherwise).

I hope I'm clear enough...

Thank you all !

EDIT:

I tried that way:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
     bookings: [
      { 
        hour: '1',
        court: '3',
        name: 'Laurent'
       },
      { 
        hour: '2',
        court: '2',
        name: 'Gaspard'
       }
    ]

  }
})
```

And

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
<table>
<tr v-for="hour in (7, 24)" :key="hour">
  <td v-for="court in (1,6)" :key="court">
    <div v-if="">

    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

But I don't kow how to link the data to the template...

Comment: please provide an example of what you have tried, so we can help you further :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a method that filters the bookings by the court and hour indexes in your loop.

```
methods: {
    getBookings( hour, court ) {
        return this.bookings.filter( booking => booking.hour == hour && booking.court == court );
    },
},
```

This returns an array of appointments so I'd use v-for instead of v-if. This means less code in the js, you don't have special code to handle the case where the returned array is empty, and your code will show if you have double bookings.

```
<div v-for="booking in getBookings( hour, court )" >
    {{ booking.name }}
</div>
```